# First order logic: $T \nvDash ^t a \iff$ there exists a structure s.t that $T \cup$ {$\lnot$ a} is valid in that structure

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

**Question:**
Prove or disprove (in first order logic) given that a is a formula, $T$ is a set of formulae: 
$T \nvDash ^t a \iff$ there exists a structure s.t. that $T \cup \{\neg a\}$ is valid in that structure.

**Tries:**
I've successfully proved the $\Leftarrow$ side of the proof, but I just feel that I don't have enough information in order to prove the other side, which leads me to search for a counterexample. I was wondering if the counterexample should s.t. $T$ is the empty set (so every structure $M$ will satisfy it) and a should be some contradiction?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @user1685224: I think that André was wondering about the symbol $\not\vDash^t$, not about $T$; certainly that’s what’s puzzling me. I understand $\vDash$, but not this.

Comment: We defined this sign in class as such that if $T \vDash ^t a$ then there for every structure and a model $M,v$ : if $M,v \vDash$ T then $M,v \vDash a$

Comment: If so, the "weird" symbol $T \vDash^t a$ reads : "$a$ is a *logical consequence* of $T$". Having said that, we must have : $T⊭^t a ⟺$ there exists a structure s.t that $T \cup \{ \lnot a \}$ is valid in that structure.

Comment: Correct, fixed it again... (I copied the question incorrectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\Rightarrow$ : it holds for *sentences*, i.e. closed formuale.

For a counter-example, consider that $T⊭a$, means that, for some *structure* $M$ and variable assignment $v$ :

> $M,v \vDash T$ and $M,v \nvDash a$.

We assume that a formula $a$ is *valid* in a structure $M$ if $M,v \vDash a$, for any $v$.

Thus consider as $T$ the Peano axioms for *arithmetic* and consider as $a$ the *formula* : $x=0$.

Then $T \nvDash (x=0)$ becuase with a $v$ such that $v(x)=1$ we have that $M,v \nvDash (x=0)$ for any structure $M$ that satisfies $T$.

But for such $M$, $T \cup \{ \lnot (x = 0) \}$ is not *valid*, because for $v'$ such that $v'(x)=0$ we have $M, v' \nvDash \lnot (x=0)$.

Comment: I have a problem with the quantifiers: For some structure M we have that there EXISTS some v such that $M,v \vDash T $ but $M,v \nvDash a $. From what I understand I need to prove that FORALL v , $M,v \vDash T \cup a$ (that's the definition of being valid in M)- where am I losing you?

Comment: @user1685224 - you are right; moving from $M⊭a$ to $M, \vDash \lnot a$ holds only for a *sentence* $a$, i.e. $a$ closed.